# Solidity Declaration error related to Wallets in Money paid section

Tags: solidity, remix, function-declaration

I'm new to solidity

My goal is to get this code to work in remix IDE solidity compiler

The code is a "for" function that is meant to trigger when deceased = true, (The code is for an inheritance contract) but it is having problems with "wallet" part of the code on the final two lines.

I've tried looking on here and elsewhere (such as Solidity/Remix IDE documentation) to find a solution but struggling with this particular problem.

Ive tried removing the "[i]", adding ";" and adding a underscore at the beginning wallet (such as "_wallets")

This is the code in question that is having issues:

```
function setup(address _wallet, uint _inheritance) public oneOwner {
    _wallet.push(_wallet);
    Inheritance [_wallet] = _inheritance; 
}

function moneyPaid() private isDeceased {
    for (uint i=0; i < wallets.length; i++) {
        wallets;[i].transfer(Inheritance[wallets][i]);
    }
}
```

These are the errors I'm shown:

DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.

```
|
36 | for (uint i=0; i < wallet.length; i++) {
|                       ^^^^^^
```

---

DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.

```
|
37 | wallets;[i].transfer(Inheritance[wallets][i]);
|    ^^^^^^^
```

---

DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.

```
|
37 | wallets;[i].transfer(Inheritance[wallets][i]);
|                                     ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not declared the variable wallets..

In for loop, you mistakenly added semicolon after wallets;

```
wallets[i].transfer(Inheritance[wallets][i]);
```

Also add or give reference to your Inherited Contract too for better understanding the issue..